# I have created an email analyzer using uax_url_email in ElasticSearch. How can I use it in a filter like this?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have created an email analyzer using uax_url_email in ElasticSearch (named as email-analyzer). How can I use it in a filter like this?

```
{
        "query" : {
            "filtered" : {
                "filter" : { "term" : { "category" : "100" }},
                "filter" : { "term" : { "email" : "test@test.com" }},
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    { "match": { "title": "something" }}
                ],
                  "minimum_should_match": "100%" 
                }
              }
              }
            },
            "highlight": {
                "fields" : {
                    "title" : {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```